# Virtual webcams under MacOS 10.15 or later

Tags: mac

Has anyone managed to get a virtual webcam functioning under MacOS 10.15 or later?
I used to use CamTwist but it doesn't seem to appear as a source in Google Hangouts any more.  Apparently WireCast works, but I'm looking for a free solution if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed that 'OBS mac virtualcam' is now working on 10.15 - would be interested to see any alternative versions
https://github.com/johnboiles/obs-mac-virtualcam